# Plot between range

Tags: plotting

I'm attempting to plot $4 \pi t$ between $[-\pi,\pi]$. I know of the `PlotRange -> {-Pi, Pi}`, but that cuts off the values outside of the range instead of constraining them.

Here is what I currently have with `Plot[4*Pi*t, {t, -Pi, Pi}]`:

[image: phase]

What I want is a graph between $[-\pi,\pi]$ such that the graph repeats and looks like a sawtooth.

How do I do this in Mathematica. ~I think Matlab does this by default.~ (It doesn't)

**Solution by J.M.:**

`Plot[Mod[4*Pi*t, {-Pi, Pi}], {t, -2, 2}]`
[image: solution]

Comment: Have you seen [`SawtoothWave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SawtoothWave.html)?

Comment: Maybe Edmund's answer combined with `Exclusions -> None`? By default, `4*Pi*t` is periodic in Matlab?! What do you mean?

Comment: @anderstood, be assured that there is no such nonsense in MATLAB.

Comment: If you don't like `SawtoothWave[]` as Edmund suggested, you can use `Mod[]`.

Comment: @J.M. `Mod[]` works perfectly! I did `Plot[Mod[4*Pi*t, {-Pi, Pi}], {t, -Pi, Pi}]` and it looks just how I wanted it.

Comment: One potential issue with what you have as your answer: it's two functions you're plotting. Check out this: `Plot[Evaluate@Mod[4*Pi*t, {-Pi, Pi}], {t, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: One final note, this is a single function that does the job: `Plot[SawtoothWave[{-Pi, Pi}, 4 t + .5], {t, -2, 2}]`